# How to make animation when composing mp4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

This code compose 3 mp4 into 1 with ffmepg, it works, but there is no animation:

```
ffmpeg()
                    .input(`./media/001.mp4`)
                    .inputFormat('mp4')
                    .input(`/tmp/looped_video.mp4`)
                    .inputFormat('mp4')
                    .input(`./media/003.mp4`)
                    .inputFormat('mp4')
                    .noAudio()
                    .videoCodec('libx264')
                    .format('mp4')
                    .complexFilter([
                        '[0]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]',
                        '[1]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]',
                        `[2]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]`,
                        `[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0`,
                    ])
                    .outputOptions([
                        '-tune animation',
                        '-loop 1',
                        '-profile:v baseline',
                        '-level 3.0',
                        '-preset medium',
                        '-threads 4',
                    ])
                    .output(`/tmp/output.mp4`)
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('MP4 video generated')
                        const endTime = Date.now()
                        console.log(
                            `FFmpeg took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds to render.`
                        )
                    })
                    .on('error', (e) => {
                        console.log(e)
                    })
                    .run()
```

I tried adding animation like this

```
ffmpeg()
                    .input(`./media/001.mp4`)
                    .inputFormat('mp4')
                    .input(`/tmp/looped_video.mp4`)
                    .inputFormat('mp4')
                    .input(`./media/003.mp4`)
                    .inputFormat('mp4')
                    .noAudio()
                    .videoCodec('libx264')
                    .format('mp4')
                    .complexFilter([
                        '[0]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]',
                        '[1]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]',
                        `[2]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]`,
                        '[0:v][1:v]crossfade=duration=1[faded]',
                        `[faded][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0`,
                    ])
                    .outputOptions([
                        '-tune animation',
                        '-loop 1',
                        '-profile:v baseline',
                        '-level 3.0',
                        '-preset medium',
                        '-threads 4',
                        '-map [faded]',
                    ])
                    .output(`/tmp/output.mp4`)
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log('MP4 video generated')
                        const endTime = Date.now()
                        console.log(
                            `FFmpeg took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds to render.`
                        )
                    })
                    .on('error', (e) => {
                        console.log(e)
                    })
                    .run()
```

but it raise an error:

```
yarn run dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ ts-node index.ts
MP4 video generated
FFmpeg took 2063 milliseconds to render.
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/janoskukoda/Workspace/test/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22)
```

---

I tried `xfade` filter also, but raise an error:

```
.complexFilter([
                        '[0:v]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]',
                        '[1:v]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]',
                        `[2:v]pad=1080:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]`,
                        `[v0][v1]xfade=duration=1:offset=3:crossfade=1[xf0]`,
                        `[xf0][v2]xfade=duration=1:offset=3:crossfade=1[out]`,
                    ])
```

> Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing complex filters.
> Option not found

Comment: You will need to use the xfade filter: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade

Comment: I tried `xfade` filter also, but raise an error, would you look at my post?

Comment: See the syntax in the example: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-137